# How to use php json_encoded array in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, json

In my php code, I have

```
 <?php
      $test = json_encode($array);//$array is a valid multidimensional array
 ?>
```

I am passing this variable to a javascript function and I am trying to set this variable to javascript.

```
 <script>
     var test = "<?php echo $test;?>";
  </script>
```

(To clarify I am using codeigniter framework and for simplicity I did not use how I am sending the variable to the page)

But when I execute the above code, I am getting

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I have checked all my syntax.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to just assign the JSON string...or did you want to assign the array? If so, you need to use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: can you `var_dump $test`, or can you post the source from your browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't put the decoded json array inside double quotes in the javascript. Change to this.

```
var test = <?php echo $test;?>;
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. I changed double quote to single quote before checking the answer and that worked as well..

Answer (score 2):

It's not required to wrap the output of json_encode in quotes, otherwise it will be interpreted as a string. At which point you'll need to decode it within JavaScript.